# ag-grid + react: checkboxSelection does not update state

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

```
const columnsTaenzer = [{
    headerName: "Any name",
    field: "yesno",
    checkboxSelection: (params: any) => {
        return (state.booleanValue) ? true : false;
    }
}, ...
```

I would like to show the checkbox depending on the value of a state value.

First time when it renders the "booleanValue" is false. But when I change the state of the boolean value, checkboxSelection does not recognize the change.

In the function checkboxSelection of ag-grid the state.booleanValue is always false. Also when I set valueCache to false and call refreshCells() with the force parameter the function checkboxSelection has always the state.booleanValue false.

How can I tell ag-grid that the state value has changed?

```
<AgGridReact
    rowHeight={50}
    rowSelection={'multiple'}
    rowDeselection={true}
    columnDefs={columnsTaenzer}
    onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
    onFirstDataRendered={autoSizeAll}
    rowData={state.tabledata}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}>
</AgGridReact>
```

**//SOLUTION (UPDATE - not working)**

Maybe not the correct one, but it works.
Use context:
[Ag-grid Context](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context/)
These parameters in combination with redrawRows() works. Only redrawRows() will trigger "checkboxSelection". If you want to trigger valueGetter only, use refreshCells({force: true})

The problem now:

If you call redrawRows, it will update the table (great), but the context will be updated at latest.

That means it will update every cell, with the old context

//Update

Everyone should have a look at [react-table](https://github.com/tanstack/table). We switched to this library and everything is working like a charm.

Comment: Can I see your setup for your ag-grid component? `<AgGridReact ..... />`?

Comment: @wentjun added aggridReact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a working plunker for your requirement (updating checkboxSelection with state update):**
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/e5sKiz13v93Gg1oV

You can use context to pass the value of boolean.
I tried doing what you are trying to achieve, and it seems to be working. AgGrid is getting the latest value of context. Maybe there is some issue with your code implementation. see above plunkr for working code. I created it by extending code at -  https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#example-multiple-row-selection

What you have to do is that, when you click on "toggle checkbox", you can do either

```
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState(p => {
              this.gridOptions.context = !p.isCheckboxShown; //set opposite value as of state before state is updated
              this.gridApi.redrawRows();
              return { isCheckboxShown: !p.isCheckboxShown };
            });
          }}
```

or

```
         onClick={() => {
            this.setState(
              p => {
                return { isCheckboxShown: !p.isCheckboxShown };
              },
              () => {
                this.gridOptions.context = this.state.isCheckboxShown;  //set same value as of state after state is updated
                this.gridApi.redrawRows();
              }
            );
          }}
```

Also, you might also want to  set `suppressRowClickSelection={true}`. When this is true, row selection won't happen when rows are clicked. Use when you want checkbox selection exclusively.

Comment: In my case I needed to do context.myprop = 'some' instead of context = { myprop: 'some' } which is related to how vue handles binding